# AWS Route53 - ChangeRecordSet - DELETE - change status is 'INSYNC' but actual records never get deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am deleting a CNAME and an A record as part of as single ChangeRecordSet using AWS CLI.

When I submit the request, the returned initial status is `PENDING` and once the request is complete, the status for the change-set is `INSYNC`, expected behavior as per documentation.

But the actual record-sets in the hosted-zone remain and never get deleted for some reason and remain 'dangling' in some sense.

Would someone know the reason for this behavior and maybe how this can be fixed, maybe something to cleanup after the `INSYNC` status ?

PS: I am able to manually delete the said records from the AwS console successfully.

Comment: Could it be a DeletionPolicy preventing them from being deleted?

Comment: @Christian a `DeletionPolicy` seems to be a Cloudformation specific property.  The records I am talking about here were created separately (CLI/API) and not using a Cloudformation template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - I was using `external-dns` to manage host name mappings and whenever I deleted the hosted-zone record using AWS CLI, it would re-create it.  Also, there is a policy for `external-dns` called `upsert-only` which doesn't synchronize deletions.  It has to be set to `sync` for the deletions to sync as well.